# Option to print output to screen or given file name (c++)

Tags: c++, file

I would like option 2 to pass the output to a typed file name. However, the program is creating the file but not passing the output to the file. I think just using ostream is fine here, but don't know how to go about it.

```
void displayTable(int n, char op) {
    int printOption;
    string outputFileName;
    ofstream createOutputFile;

    while (true) { //option for print screen or print to file
        cout << "Select: \n1) Print on Screen \n2) Print to a file name \nSelection: ";
        cin >> printOption;

        if (printOption == 1)
            break;
        else if (printOption == 2){
            cout << "Type in the name for the output file." << endl;
            cin >> outputFileName;
            createOutputFile.open(outputFileName);
            break;
        }
        else
            cout << "Please enter a valid number." << endl;
    }

    int max = getMaxSize(n, op);
    cout << setw(max) << op << "|";
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        cout << setw(max) << i;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
        cout << "-";
    }
    cout << "+";
    for (int i = 0; i < n * max; ++i) {
        cout << "-";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        cout << setw(max) << i << "|";
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j) {
            cout << setw(max) << getValue(i, j, op);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    createOutputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: The shown code in this question does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone here can conclusively determine the problem, but only guess, at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing anything to `createOutputFile`, everything is being printed to `cout` instead. That is why to don't see anything in the file, and everything in the console.

The easiest way to solve your issue is to redirect `cout` to `createOutputFile`'s output buffer, eg:

```cpp
auto cout_buff = cout.rdbuf();
...
createOutputFile.open(outputFileName);
cout.rdbuf(createOutputFile.rdbuf())
// all cout outputs will now go to the file...
...
cout.rdbuf(cout_buff); // restore when finished...
```

Otherwise, move your print logic to a separate function that takes an `ostream&` as a parameter:

```cpp
void doMyLogic(ostream &os)
{
    // print to os as needed...
}

...

if (printOption == 1) {
    doMyLogic(cout);
    break;
} 
if (printOption == 2) {
    ...
    ofstream createOutputFile(outputFileName);
    doMyLogic(createOutputFile);
    break;
}
...
```